# PHP openssl_sign outputs weird characters

Tags: php, utf-8, openssl

I am trying to sign a file using openssl_sign.

My code:

```
$pkeyid = openssl_get_privatekey($priv_key); 

// compute signature
openssl_sign($data, $signature, $pkeyid, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1);

Echo $signature;

// free the key from memory
openssl_free_key($pkeyid);
```

The problem is that it is outputing weird characters and not a sha1 hash. What am I doing Wrong? (My PHP file is encoded in UTF8)

The output:

> šòŠµcÔÝ”Kÿ­LÍvÎ*q‡m—Xz¬ëNðñÆÒÐLÉ6Š²cTO¯à„ØæØSª?tšü
>   T/ß‹‡‚¤Sý³f¥Jª¥§š¯ŠqL¾ð›‹å-éuÇ–Öºþ¦ùn}"Ë?=˜JTÃj)ŒÉ~ˆ×†±ÍçÏZ5]þNÉÌO­hÔMllCJY`k—W²IHrätv¨ôñ  IµBÛÕBô€ŸIwèFd8
>   êÿ2äåçAØèÙtªˆÈÚ‡¹œ£šO.èiÿonE[ÑœZºZ @TpÉO•Ý˜~ëq

Was expecting something like:

> Ol2rr4oaPHxfQL4ER8Ck15OEr8D8Cn9iGcsjZ8ves2IG7WOFFm0WUyQDAN30trNvO7vRQF25Uosw/Aflx3bRB1ezQNSn6mPvTzU6CPuSC+BBddytOyRvoLPhJ4F910yE8mrKeIuz1un8Dobm3PnZrlwCJecQbSilE4uIJ2rikl4=

PS: $data contains a text that I am trying to sign. The private key is correctly loaded and I manually put it inside my file. (it is pem formated)

Comment: OKay it seems that the output is in a binary format. I used base64_encode and now it is outputing something more logical. Sstill running some tests.

The weird part is that nowhere it says that...

Comment: I dont think this is a sha1 hash after a few atempts. I still cant get it to work... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Only cast your string to

```
$signature = base64_encode($signtaure);
echo"The sring hash is;".$signature;
```

before save on ani flie or variable

The SHA1 encryption is not the problem.

If you want to verify the sign

```
$privateKeyPem = file_get_contents($folder.'private_key.pem');
               $publicKeyPem = file_get_contents($folder.'public_key.pem');

               $signature = file_get_contents($folder.'signature.dat');

                 $signature = base64_decode($signature);
                 //echo "the signature is: ".$signature; for verify your string
               if (openssl_verify($stringtosign, $signature, $publicKeyPem, 'sha256WithRSAEncryption') === 1) {
                   echo 'the sign is a valid sign ';

                 echo'<br> the generated hash is: '.$signature;
               } else {
                   echo 'the sign is invalid';
               }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the binary into hexadecimal

```
$signature = bin2hex($signature);
```